# What is the best way to assert that a set of columns could form a primary key in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, primary-key, assert

Infamously primary key constraints are [**not enforced**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html) in snowflake sql:

```sql
-- Generating a table with 4 rows that contain duplicates and NULLs:
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE PRIMARY_KEY_TEST AS
SELECT
*
FROM (
           SELECT 1    AS PK, 'TEST_TEXT' AS TEXT
UNION ALL  SELECT 1    AS PK, 'TEST_TEXT' AS TEXT
UNION ALL  SELECT NULL AS PK, NULL        AS TEXT
UNION ALL  SELECT NULL AS PK, NULL        AS TEXT
)
;

SELECT *
FROM PRIMARY_KEY_TEST
;
```

| PK | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST_TEXT |
| 1 | TEST_TEXT |
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |

```sql
-- These constraints will NOT throw any errors in Snowflake
ALTER TABLE PRIMARY_KEY_TEST ADD PRIMARY KEY (PK);
ALTER TABLE PRIMARY_KEY_TEST ADD UNIQUE (TEXT);
```

However knowing that a set of colums has values that are **uniuqe for every row** and **never `NULL`** is vital to check when updating a set of data.

So I'm looking for a easy to write and read (ideally 1-2 lines) piece of code (proably based on some Snowflake function) that throws an error if a set of columns no longer forms a viable primary key in Snowflake SQL.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I'm looking for a easy to write and read (ideally 1-2 lines) piece of code (proably based on some Snowflake function) that throws an error if a set of columns no longer forms a viable primary key in Snowflake SQL

Such test query is easy to write using `QUALIFY` and windowed COUNT. The pattern is to place primary key column list into PARTITION BY part and search for non-unique values, additional check for nulls could be added too. If the column list is a valid candidate for Primary key, it will not return any rows, if there are rows violating the rules they will be returned:

```
-- checking if PK is applicable
SELECT *
FROM PRIMARY_KEY_TEST
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PK) > 1
     OR PK IS NULL;
  
 -- chekcing if TEXT column is applicable 
SELECT *
FROM PRIMARY_KEY_TEST
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TEXT) > 1
     OR TEXT IS NULL;
     
 -- chekcing if PK,TEXT columns are applicable 
SELECT *
FROM PRIMARY_KEY_TEST
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PK,TEXT) > 1
    OR PK IS NULL
    OR TEXT IS NULL;
```

---

> *I'd still prefer code that can throw an error though*

It is possible using Snowflake Scripting and [RAISE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/raise.html) exception:

```
BEGIN
   LET my_exception EXCEPTION (-20002, 'Columns cannot be used as PK.');

   IF (EXISTS(SELECT *
             FROM PRIMARY_KEY_TEST
              QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PK) > 1
               OR PK IS NULL
       )) THEN
     RAISE my_exception;
  END IF;
END;
```

> -20002 (P0001): Uncaught exception of type 'MY_EXCEPTION' on line 8 at position 5 : Columns cannot be used as PK.

Comment: I like it! (It's cleaner, than what I used until now, which was a nested query and a where instead of the simple query with a qualify) I'd still prefer code that can throw an error though.

Comment: @SamFed Snowflake Scripting allow to raise user defined exceptions

Answer (score 0):

you can enforce NOT NULL in Snowflake by adding a NOT NULL constraint on the columns which you want not to be null able.

The primary key constraint is informational only; It is not enforced when you insert the data into a table. For primary key you will have to either remove / delete the data or before inserting you will have to check if the data exists then you only update.
Depending upon what you are doing you may use the following

1. Merge (insert and update)
2. Use Distinct to check if the row exist then update or delete the old  and insert the new.
3. You could use ROW_NUMBER analytical function to identify the duplicates.